# dynamic update strong params in rails 4 based condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have 3 models which is

`User : id,email`

`Presentation : id,title,description,avatar_filename,avatar_content_type,avatar_file_size`

`Webnair : id,user_id,presentation_id,choice,title,description,pptfilename,pptcontent_type,pptfile_size`

choice is boolean in that Webnair model, I've assumed 1-newpresentation, 0-select from list in db

In webnaircontroller.rb I want check condtion in creat method:

```
 def create
   @webnair = Webnair.new(webnairs_params)
     if @webnair.save!
       flash[:notice] = "Webnair created successfully!"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Webnair not created!"
      end
    redirect_to root_path
end
private 

  def webnairs_params
  if params[:choice].to_s == "1"
   webnairs_params = params.require(:webnair).permit(:user_id, :ppt, :choice,     :title,:description)     
else
webnairs_params = params.require(:webnair).permit(:user_id, :presentation_id, choice,:title, :description) 
end
end
```

Comment: Check colon before 'choice' in else condition.

Comment: I solve the solution...!